# How harm it can be to combine an update/create/delete REST request?

Tags: architecture, rest, enterprise-architecture

Currently I have being request do implement an endpoint that would be responsible to update/create/delete sub-items for a single entity. The entities in case are students in a given classroom and the request would send the current status (number of students) in the given class. To summarize we have classroom that has a list of student which we can add, update and delete. So, all the logic related to identify which student should be updated (read from database the ones that are stored and compare with the ones received in the request), deleted (check the ones on the database that weren't received received in the request) and finally add (check the ones on the request that aren't on the database) are done in the back end.

This is a very weird think to do, but I can reason well enough to justify how harm this could be in terms of, separate of concerns, business logic, debugging, etc.

Comment: Maybe more of a semantical argument, but I would describe that endpoint as an **import** endpoint, rather than a CRUD one. Imports have CRUDs underlying them, but the name very much reveals that this is a bulk data operation, as opposed to targeting a specific resource.

Answer (score 2):

For a request like

```
PUT /class/:id/attendance

<list of students>
```

I would find the steps you list to be a very reasonable way to implement the required semantics of setting the list if attending students to the provided list.

Another way would be to blindly delete the current list from the database and then add the provided list, but there can be reasons to limit the number of unneeded changes made to the database.

Given that, there is nothing wrong with your assignment. The end-point has just a single concern (also from a business perspective) and that is to replace the list of attendants to a class.

Answer (score 1):

In your case i would expect that the client is specificly build for the backend and vice versa. That means, you do not expect that anybody else will ever use this endpoint, beside your client.

The interesting thing about REST is, that its original use case was the internet. That means, someone provides an endpoint, and somebody unknown will use it. This creates a lot of restrictions. Especially about the use of HTTP methods. In such a situation, you want very clear API´s. There you do not want a POST request, that also reads, creates, updates and deletes things. It would make it quite hard for others to use the API safely. Because it does not behave as expected.

In the case that the backend and the client are the only players and they both belong to the same team / project (good communication between client and backend developers), there its less relevant to be predictable.
But be aware, **less** does not mean **not**. For new developers in the team it will still be awkward. They see the request and will not expect such a behavior.

In your case your have two information objects. The class and the students. You want to update the ressource "class" and combine that with an update of the ressources "student" in that class. From an REST perspective i would handle those ressources indepently. Because updating students information has nothing to do with updating the participation of that student in a class. If you combine that, then there could be unexpected behavior.
Think about the trainer of Class A and the trainer of Class B would like to update their participation list. Student X participated in both classes. The Trainer of Class A also knows that X has changed his address. Trainer of A and Trainer B load the current data, then Trainer A is updating in his client the data of X and adds him to his class. Trainer B also adds X to his class (with the old student data). Now Trainer A sends the data (class and student get updated) and now Trainer B sends the data (class B gets updated and the students data gets overwritten by the old data).

With seperated ressources you do not have the problem. Trainer A would update student X and add the student to his class. Trainer B would just add the student to his class. No problem there.

Therefore the approach you were asked for has two problems. One is that its mixing the manipulation of two different ressources at the same time (see example above). The other is, that its mixing different kinds of manipulation of one ressource (Create, Update, Delete).

The second problem is not as bad as the first. But still a problem.
As said in the beginning, a new developer will not expect that a POST is doing all that stuff.
*REST => Representational state transfer => is an architectural style*
That means this is focused on representation of data. What you were asked to do is calling a function in the backend which does stuff. So my first question would be if REST is the right communication style here.

So, i would not talk about REST, but only about HTTP(S) (thats just the protocol layer, often used by REST architectures but not limited to them).
POST, by [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST), is not idempotent and allows side effects. The same is true for [PATCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH). Therefore, the wanted behavior (of side effects) would fit in there. POST for a new class or updating one, PATCH only for updating an existent one by sending only the changed data.
Sounds reasonable.

Personaly i would at least split the functionality on the backend side in seperate modules. One for handling the students. One for handling the class data. In those i would seperate the different changes (Create, Update, Delete). To at least fulfill the SoC (Separation of Concerns) principle in the implementation, if i can´t do that already in the endpoint.
IF it is likely that a student will be updated twice at the same time (see example above), then i would choose one endpoint per ressource (class, student) to make it less likely, that a hickup occurs. Or if its a critical ressource i would add a data versioning to ensure that an update that is based on version XY of that data is only applied to the data if its still version XY.

By the way, by seperating the ressources you could also apply a stricter security to it. The information that a student with id XY has participated in class YZ is not very valuable. The information that there were 25 students in class YZ is not valuable. But if you get all the personal data of the students (name, address, ...) with it, then this is valuable data. So, from a security point of view, the data should definitly be seperated.

I hope that long sermon helps a bit.